# npm run build для Vue js выдаёт пустую страницу на сервере

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, spa

Пытаюсь развернуть проект на хостинге, пустая страница, уже как ни пробовал искать ответы, менять пути маршрутизации  assetsPublicPath: с '/' на './' и '', всё равно результат тот же.

nmp run dev на localhost при этом открывается нормально. Вот источник: https://github.com/michaelcheng924/vue-firestore-tutorial

В консоли браузера вроде ошибок даже никаких нет, выдаёт пустую страницу и всё. Что мне нужно сделать для корректного запуска build-версии?

Comment: нужно менять настройки сервера так, чтобы при обращении к нему он отдавал файлы сборки.

Comment: npm run build выдает ошибку, или билдится но на сервере не работает? мб вам надо .htaccess для этого что на сервере он увидел его

Comment: билдится, но на сервере не работает, htaccess тоже пробовал ставить, 0 реакции что-то